# Permalink misbehaving in Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, permalinks, url-rewriting

I have a post type named careers which is,

```
function do_careers() {
 register_post_type('Careers', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Careers',
        'singular_name' => 'Career',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Career',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Career',
    ),
    'description' => 'Careers',
    'public' => true,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'supports' => array('title')
 ));
}

add_action('init', 'do_careers');
```

And for the purpose of having `/blog/` in permalink of posts I have the custom permalink structure like,

`/blog/%postname%/`

When I have `/blog/` part in the custom permalink I see the career permalink like this `https://www.abcd.net/blog/careers/blah-blah-blah/`.

When I only have the `/%postname%/` in custom permalink I can see that my blog post permalink shows like `https://www.abcd.net/blah-blah-blah/`. Part`/blog/` is not here, but career link is perfect like `https://www.abcd.net/careers/blah-blah-blah/`.

I want then permalink in the following pattern for all posts(including custom post types).

`https://www.abcd.net/post_type/post_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rewrite` argument of `register_post_type()` will help you with this. The `rewrite` argument is an array of different arguments, the one you'll need is `with_front`, which desides whether the permalink base is prepended to your post type. It defaults to true, setting it to false will not include the permalink structure in the permalink. It would look something like this:

```
function do_careers() {
 register_post_type('Careers', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Careers',
        'singular_name' => 'Career',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Career',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Career',
    ),
    'description' => 'Careers',
    'public' => true,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'supports' => array('title'),
    'rewrite' => array(
        'with_front' => false,
    ),
 ));
}

add_action('init', 'do_careers');
```

You can also add a `slug` argument to the `rewrite` array to make the post type slug different from the post type name, if you wish to do so.